# Book to learn the use of complex number to solve geometric problem

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation, complex-geometry

I want to learn to use complex number to solve geometric problems, Specially to solve olympiad questions. There are a couple of books in the market and i am confused which one should i buy.

Here is some of them---

1. Geometry of complex number, Hans Schwedtfeger
2. Introduction to the geometry of complex number, Ronald Deaux
3. Complex number and geometry, liang shin hahn
4. Complex number in geometry.

I am a very beginner at this thing. I do not know a thing about using complex number in geometry. Some hard and too much advanced book won't suite me.

Comment: See here http://yisun.io/notes/complex.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Complex Numbers from A to ... Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/081768414X) by Titu Andreescu and Dorin Andrica might suit you. It starts out on a basic level and finishes with Olympiad-level problems.

From the preface: “The targeted audience includes high school students and their teachers, undergraduates, mathematics contestants such as those training for Olympiads or the W. L. Putnam Mathematical Competition, their coaches, and any person interested in essential
mathematics.”

Comment: Thank you very much. How much time do you think will take to master the basics

Comment: @sakib: Oh, that's very individual, so it's impossible for me to say.

Comment: Hmm thats true. I have downloaded it and liked the table of contents. The way it's arranged is very good and convenient. I think a good amount time, devotion and practice wont take much time

Comment: An off topic related to this question, can you recommend books for learning coordinate geometry and trilinear coordinates

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what “trilinear coordinates” are...! And coordinate geometry seems like schoolbook stuff, I don't have any particular recommendations for that.

Answer (score 2):

Repeating an 
[earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85244/237),
I suggest:

Tristan Needham,
[Visual Complex Analysis](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//), Oxford Univ. Press, 1998.

---

[image: Needham cover]

---

Comment: You know i am a very beginner at this thing. I do not know a thing about using complex number in geometry. Some hard and too much advanced book won't suite me. So will this book be convenient for me? :)

Comment: @sakib: Perhaps not.

Comment: @sakib: It's an absolutely wonderful book which I can definitely recommend in general, but probably not very useful for learning to solve olympiad geometry problems.